# Duplication of unfiltered records on reload of filtered record in ExtJS Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

Duplicate records are being created on load of grid after deleting filtered records. After applying filter to one or more columns.

[Link to my Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qo7)

Steps to replicate bug:

1. Filter records by name either John or bob
2. Click refresh button
3. Remove filter completely

Comment: It's not happening in 5.1.1.451 you should upgrade your framework version. If you are unable to upgrade your framework you can ask Sencha Support for custom override fix of this bug.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a bug in version 5, because in the latest versions this error does not occur. However, one way to resolve this is to check the [`filterchange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#event-filterchange) event of your store.

```
listeners: {
    filterchange: function (a, b, c) {
        if(!b[0]){
            this.load();
        }
    }
}
```

Where the second parameter `b`, is an array of [`Ext.util.Filter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.util.Filter.html).
So just check, if this array is empty, then reload your store.

[Fiddle version 6, with no changes.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qoh)

[Fiddle version 5, with changes.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qok)